# Preiodically read zookeeper node

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a use case where I want to read the zookeeper nodes periodically. Is there any way I can do this in zookeeper asynchronously?

I read about `exists()` but it call backs only if there is a change in node data.

Comment: Why would you want to read it even if the data is not changed after the last read ? If the client put a watch for data change events, then it is notified and hence can always have the latest data.

Comment: There is another application(say X) which updates the nodes periodically. If the application(X) goes down it will not update the zookeeper nodes. My application(Y) has to check for the time stamp of nodes and if the time stamp hasn't been updated for quite some time it will restart the application(X) assuming the application(X
) is down.

Since there is no service which will give me constant update about the zookeeper nodes I will have to poll the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java with Spring, create a component with a method with the annotation @Scheduled. Add a delay and inside the method put the code where you read the zNode and check if the other application is alive.